# Insert line break when writing to file?

Tags: java, file-io

So My code looks like this:

```
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher (line);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));

            //the println puts linebreak after each find

            String filename= "page.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
            fw.write(m.group(1));
            fw.close();

            //the fw writes everything after each find with no line break
    }
}
```

I get right form of output at line `System.out.println(m.group(1));` However when I later on want to write what is shown by `m.group(1)` It writes to file without putting linebreak since the code doesn't have one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just call `fw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`.

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` will give you the line separator for your platform (whether Windows or some Unix flavor).

Answer (score 1):

just do

```
fw.write("\n");
```

that will put an escape character for a new line

Comment: But if you open a file generated that way in Notepad under Windows, you won't see the line endings.

Comment: thanks but yes it would be better that it also get organized in file too :)

Answer (score 1):

`println(text)` adds the line break to the string, and is essentially the same as `print(text); print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`.

So in order to add the line break you have to do the same.

However, to improve your code, I have two recommendations:

1. Don't create a new `FileWriter` in the loop. Create it outside the loop and close it after the loop.
2. Don't use a `FileWriter`, but instead a `PrintWriter` wrapped around a `FileWriter`. Then you get the same `println()` method as `System.out`.

Comment: thx I keep that in mind . at the moment since I just began coding in java I want to get the job done . I get to trimming , optimizing codes later when I have wider view of java :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead **System.getProperty("line.separator")** also **System.lineSeparator()**